# django template for in for

Tags: django, templates

Any idea why this doesn't work? It gives me an error at `{% if tab.title==foc %}`

```
{% for tab in menu %}
  {% for foc in focus  %}
    <li>{{ tab.title }}</li>
    {% if tab.title==foc %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what error does it give? Could it be a problem with the foc or tab variables?

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '==foc' from 'tab.title==foc'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with spaces around ==

Alternatively, use the **[ifqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal)** tag instead of **if**

Answer (score 0):

The [if](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#if) statement was introduced on django [1.2 alpha](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2-alpha-1/#smart-if-tag) and modified on django [1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#smart-if-tag)

The right way of using it:

```
{% if somevar == "x" %}
    This appears if variable somevar equals the string "x"
{% endif %}
```

Check your django version at your django console with:

```
django.version
```

And if you using a lesser than 1.2 you should use the [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal) tag